# How do I extract elements from a dataframe by pattern?

Tags: r, dataframe, design-patterns, indexing, extract

I have a dataframe `dat` that has many variables like

```
"x_tp1_y"
"g_tp1_z"
"f_tp2_h"
```

I would like to extract elements that include `"tp1"`.

I already tried this:

```
grep("tp1", dat)

grepl("tp1", dat)

dat["tp1",]
```

I just want R to give me elements with this pattern so I do not have to type in all variable names that are in the dataframe `dat`.
Like this:

> command that extracts elements with pattern "tp1"
>   R returns parts of the dataframe that have pattern "tp1":

```
x_tp1_y   g_tp1_z
      1         2
      0         3
```

And then I would like to create a new dataframe.

I know that I just can use

```
newdat <- data.frame( dat[[1]], dat[ c(1:30)])
```

but I have so many elements in my dataframe that this would take ages.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: I did, hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat[,grep("tp1", colnames(dat))]
```

grep finds the index numbers in the column names of the data.frame (the vector colnames(dat))   that contain the necessary pattern. "[" subsets

Comment: You should give an explanation of what the code does. These *code-only answers* are many times flagged for deletion. (I have upvoted because it seems to answer the question but do edit the answer with a few words.)